# How to only have single direction of Jquery sortable elements between lists?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

Is their a way to enable a single direction of data, where one `table1` can only give elements and `table2` can only recieve elements?

```
$(function() {
  $( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
       connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
   }).disableSelection();
});
```

Please forgive my inexperience, any information is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [API Docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-connectWith):

> **connectWith:**
>   A selector of other sortable elements that the items from this list should be connected to. This is a **one-way relationship**, if you want the items to be connected in both directions, the connectWith option **must be set on both sortable elements**.

The code example you gave seems to be similar to that of the [jQuery UI demo site](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists). If you study the code, you'd notice the CSS class `.connectedSortable` is declared on both lists:

```
<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
    ...
</ul>

<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 1</li>
    ...
</ul>
```

The code you provided will make this sortable list bi-directional. To make it one-way, you can specify another selector:

```
$(function() {
  $( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
       connectWith: "#sortable2" // changed this to reflect the ID of the second list
   }).disableSelection();
});
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jasonnathan/xJL3W/) for example